# Using one row for different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't know what to say and I'm new to excel. Is there a way I can use the same cell with different cells? It sounds dumb I know, but here is the example formula I'm trying to use.

=H7/H6

I don't want to type and repeat the formula for 1000 times I just want to know if there is a way for it to become =H8/H6, =H9/H6, and so on.

Comment: sounds like you want to use an absolute reference `$H$6`: see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-formulas-in-excel-ecfdc708-9162-49e8-b993-c311f47ca173

Comment: @TmTron That would add the whole column, what I want to do is divide each cell from H7 to H1000 to only H6 cell and I don't want to type it individually. .

Comment: Lock the cell by using func.key (F4) then it turns to $H$6 and will get the result individual cell.

Comment: yes, you write the formula once `=H7/$H$6` and then let Excel fill the [formula down](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6#:~:text=Click%20Home%20%3E%20Fill%2C%20and%20choose,the%20right%20in%20a%20row.)